# Visualizing three parameters dataset, in which parameters are sub-group of one another

Tags: visualization, python-3.x, seaborn, plotly

I am trying to represent air quality for zones within a city. Initially, based on various factors zones were classified into four exposure categories (1,2,3,4).Those four categories were further sub-divided into three categories (1,2,3). For eg, within "Exposed 2" area of zone 1 - 14% of population will be moderately affected and 86% will be severely affected.

[image]

How to visualize this data either in plotly or seaborn. As i am very much new to both plotly and seaborn - find it very difficult to visualize this data. I have tried heatmap in both but it's working only for two parameters. But i need three parameters: Zones -> exposure level -> severity.

It's a very urgent work and i have been stuck for days. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated